# How do i make an anchor tag display a list when i click on it in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make a link drop a list for me to be able to select. When the link is clicked i want it to dropdown a list.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried already?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using html css and jquery. So i will post the code below, hope it will be helpful to you.

```
ol li m{
display: block;
```

}

```
ol {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
width: 100px;
border: 1px;
```

}

above is the CSS code.

Below you can see the HTML code.

```
<m href="reference url">Press me</a>
```

`<ol>`

`<li><m href="">first link</a></li>`

`<li><m href="">second link</a></li>`

`<li><a href="">third link</a></li>`

`</ol>`

Below you can see the Jquery part.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("m").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

});

if you want more clarification inform .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Have a look at a part of the code, I would like to click on the link email management and it brings down the list.  I do not want the list displayed until the link Email management is clicked  <a href="">Email Management </a>
        <p> IT services provide  </p>
  <ul class="list-unstyled" style="display:none"> 
   <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
   <a href="#.html"> User Account Creation </a> </li>
   <li> <a href="#.html"> Group Account Creation / Distribution List </a> </li>
  </ul>